# Node Js passing JSON to javaScript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Am new to programming. I would be glad if someone could help with this.

When I try to pass JSON data into EJS i use this

```
<%= user.username %>
```

and it works fine.

On the Other hand when I pass JSON in JavaScript. I get an error of Undefined

Here is my Code sample

**Server side**

```
router.get('/user/:id', middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req,res) {
  User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundUser) {
    if (err) {
      req.flash("error", "Error while retrieving information from database")
      res.redirect("/");
    }
    // check if user is deleted form the database
    if (!foundUser) {
        req.flash("error", "Selected user is deleted");
        return res.redirect("/");
    }
    // res.render("profile", {user:foundUser})
    Task.find().where("author.id").equals(foundUser._id).exec(function(err, foundTasks) {
      if (err) {
        req.flash("error", "Error while retrieving information from database")
        res.redirect("/");
      }
      res.render("profile", {title: "Public Profile", user:foundUser, tasks:foundTasks});

    })
  })
})
```

**EJS**

```
<p><%= user.username %> </p> //works Fine
```

**JavaScript**

```
<p><%= user.username </p><script >var $user = user.username;</script>
```

**JSON data for DBS**

```
{
fname:"Seyi",
lname:"Adewumi",
username:"seyide",
displayName:"SeyiB",
active:true
}
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: `<%- JSON.stringify(user.username) %>`

Comment: `//works Fine` really?! Arent you missing a closing `%>` ?

Comment: Look at the generated source code. Consider what `var $user = seyide` means in JavaScript. Think about the difference between a variable and a string.

Comment: @quentin and `user` is probably not defined either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass it into javascript:

```
 var $user = "<%= user.username %>";
```